# Is it a PHP or Joomla! issue? (or perhaps I'm missing something about the output buffering)

Tags: php, joomla, joomla1.6

I'm trying to integrate VideoJS in a plugin for displaying videos in blog and article view/layout. First of all, I find the plugin tag using a regular expression and the source for the video, which could be a YouTube video ID or a path to a video file:

> YouTube video source: {youtube}y0u7u83v1de0{/youtube}  Video file
>   source: {video}path/to/video.mp4{/video}

Finding those values is not the issue, the problem comes when trying to echo the video source. I'm using a stdClass object to hold the values in onContentBeforeDisplay function:

```
$width = 636; 
$height = 333; 
$youtubeCode = '/{youtube}(.*?){\/youtube}/'; 
$videoCode = '/{video}(.*?){\/video}/'; 
preg_match($youtubeCode, $article->introtext, $match); 
preg_match($videoCode, $article->introtext, $match); 
$video = new stdClass(); 
$video->source = $match[1]; 
$video->width = $width; 
$video->height = $height; 
$layout = JPATH_SITE . DS . 'plugins' . DS . $this->plugin->type . 
DS . $this->plugin->name . DS . 'tmpl' . DS . 'default.php'; 

if ($layout) { 
    ob_start(); 
    require $layout; 
    $contents = ob_get_contents(); 
    ob_end_clean(); 
    $article->introtext = $contents . $article->introtext; 
}
```

Now, the layout file just outputs the HTML video tag with the 
respective values:

```
<video id="<?= $video->id ?>" class="video-js vjs-default-skin" controls width="<?= $video->width ?>" height="<?= $video->height ?>" poster="<?= $video->images['preview'] ?>" data-setup="{techOrder: ['youtube', 'html5']}">
    <source src="<?= $video->source ?>" type="<?= $video->format ?>" /> 
</video>
```

All the values display correctly, except for the $video->source property, which before starting the output buffering still have the correct value, but seems like starting the output nullifies that particular value.

What could be causing that behavior? Something about the output buffering I might be missing?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Joomla is based on PHP you know...

Comment: I actually found the 'issue'. I doesn't have anything to do with PHP nor Joomla!. How can I close the question?

Comment: @SaulMartínez: Answer the question yourself, mark the answer.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know VideoJS and I don't know what you are trying to to *exactly* but from what I see set $video->source to $match[1] but you test the regular expression first to search a {youtube} tag and then to search a {video} tag but you use the same $match variable and you don't test if what you (eventually) find is (is a youtube video or a "normal" video?).

From what I see you access $video->format in the layout file but you don't set it.

Maybe you should write something *like this*

```
[...]
if ( preg_match($youtubeCode, $article->introtext, $match) ) {
    // found a {youtube} tag
    $video->format = "youtube";
    $video->source = $match[1];
} else if ( preg_match($videoCode, $article->introtext, $match) ) {
    // found a {video} tag
    $video->format = "video";
    $video->source = $match[1];
}

// Prepend the <video> element if {youtube} or {video} tag found
if ( $layout && !is_null($video->format) && !is_null($video->format) ) { 
    ob_start(); 
    require $layout; 
    $contents = ob_get_contents(); 
    ob_end_clean(); 
    $article->introtext = $contents . $article->introtext; 
}
```

But please pay attention because it should replace only the first tag found, if you have an article with several {youtube}/{video} tags it should not work.

Hope I've understood well what you are trying to do :P